# php send data to another php page after page loaded

Tags: javascript, php

I can pass data with this url code to my second php file.

```
www.test.com/second.php?task=demo&id=55
```

and I can pass data with this javascript code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var postdata= 'task=demo&id=55';
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'second.php',
        data:postdata,

    });
});
</script>
```

I want to pass this data `task=demo&id=55` with php, How can I do that? Thank you.

I can do this with form but I have to do this automatically after page loaded

second.php

```
$task = $_GET["task"];
$id = $_GET["id"];

...
...
...
other codes
```

Comment: What do you mean by sending it to another page? Like communicating between two open tabs?

Comment: create a form and make 2 hidden field with your data and submit the form, make the action page as second.php

Comment: The ajax request shown will do what you are asking but you haven't explained what your specific problem is with the code shown and you do nothing with the response. Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: I can do this with form but I have to do this automatically after page loaded @AzeezKallayi

Comment: a.php to b.php @Ivar

Comment: That still is unclear. Try to add a step-by-step of what you are trying to do and what you expect. Also reading [ask] might be useful.

Comment: I have added second.php @Ivar

Comment: What is the exact problem? Your code works. It sends the data to `second.php` on page load.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to pass values. If `second.php` is not executed by the same environment, then you can send the values using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ro/book.curl.php).

If you intend to redirect to the second page, then you can redirect to `second.php` using this command:

```
$youridvalue = 55;
$task = "demo";
header('Location: http://www.test.com/second.php?task='.$task.'&id='.$youridvalue);
```

If you intend to execute `second.php`, but to stay on `first.php`, then you can set the `$_GET` values, like this:

```
$_GET['task'] = 'demo';
$_GET['id'] = '55';
```

and then `require` or `include` `second.php`. However, in this case it is recommended to separate the functionality from `second.php` into a `class` or `function`, so you can reuse the functionality without the need to `include` or `require` `second.php` and/or duplicate your code on multiple places.